# Basic JavaScript - How to make a certain lines of code run before prompts/prompt-containing functions?

Tags: javascript, prompt

```
function restart_game() {
    document.getElementById("myBody").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
    finished=false;
    do_game(); //do_game() has a prompt within it that interrupts the .document line.
}
```

So let's say I want to run `document.getElementById` before `do_game()` (a function that calls a prompt) but they are called by the same function: How do I make this happen effectively?

I want them both to run but in the order that I decide, without the prompt within `do_game()` happening before my style changes in the line before. Or is there just a better way to achieve what I'm attempting to do with different code?

Any advice would be highly welcome.

Comment: The style change _should_ happen before the prompt. Are you sure this doesn't work?

Comment: They *are* running in the correct order. The problem you are getting is that the code is running in the browser's context and the screen isn't updating until the function returns.

Comment: Yeah, my apologies for the poor wording. I realize that one is being set on "hold" or something, but how do I change this prioritization or work around it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do this in order to make sure that `do_game()` runs after style changes:

```
var myBody = document.getElementById("myBody");

function restart_game() {
   myBody.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
   finished=false;
}

myBody.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function(e){
   if (e.attrName === 'style')
      do_game();
});
```

Explanation: This way, `restart_game()` function will change style of "myBody" element. When that happens, eventListener attached to "myBody" element will detect style changes and execute `do_game()` so you'll have their execution aligned.

Comment: I'm pretty new to JavaScript: is there anything I need to add to implement those last three lines of code?

Comment: I've made a mistake while coping your code, missing " before rgba property. I'll add explanation as well in answer.

Comment: And it would be nice if someone explained his or hers reason for down voting answer. I would like to learn from my mistakes so please, point them out :)

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful and I really appreciate it. Sadly, my button does not work now, however. And I would give you an upvote if I could :)

Comment: Oh, it doesn't matter. I tough I've made a mistake somewhere in code that I can't see :)

Comment: Your code is probably fine. It's more likely my implementation that is off. Thank you for the great explanation and advice. I've learned how the process functions a lot better now either way. Much appreciated.

Comment: In my oppinion you should not use events this way. This is more or less just a goto in disguise. Furthermore  it´s not unlikely that the event is called on the style attribute from another context, so using DOMEvents this way is a open door for side effects